# I am unable to enable and disable the form input fields

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, validation

I somehow can't manage to enable and disable the form fields

this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/cancerian73/YsRwH/

```
.edit-profile-text{
   font: bold 12px/12px Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
   color: #5a5b5b; margin:10px 0 30px 0; 
   background:url(../images/icons/edit-profile2.png) no-repeat 0 0; 
   padding:0 0 0 30px; 
   min-height:16px;
}
```

Please tell me what am I doing wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YsRwH/3/

Comment: You also should set id="edit" on <a> element, not on <div>.

Comment: @zzlalani: it had nothing to do with css so i didnt provide one as i gave it as an external resource. This was about jquery and my fiddle has a js if you can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two Problems

1. Form id has a `#` - remove it
2. Use `.prop()` set disabled state

try

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" id="myForm" data-validate="parsley">
```

and

```
var form = $("#myForm");
$('#edit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.find(':disabled').prop('disabled', false);
});

$('#cancel').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    form.find(':enabled').prop("disabled", true);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PEn8M/)

Answer (score 2):

You form tag is this:

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" id="#myForm" data-validate="parsley">
```

In this form you have added the `#` in the id remove that and it will work.

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" id="myForm" data-validate="parsley">
                                               ^^^ from here remove #
```

And this will be work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#edit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  $('input,select').each(function () {
        $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});

$('#cancel').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input,select').each(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
})
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YsRwH/13/)

Answer (score 0):

Use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of .attr()

According to the documentation of [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) -

> Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting value.

Answer (score 0):

Form id should `"myForm"`

```
<form name="myForm" method="post" action="" **id="myForm"** data-validate="parsley">
```

instead of '#myForm'